# Low output voltage from arduino pins problem

Tags: arduino, rfid

I using RFID module and the project working well but the only problem is low output voltage from arduino pins when i put the card near module. it is about only 2v not 5v.
i test other pins but the voltage still 2v.
how can i solve this problem?
note: i don't use resistor for LEDs because the output voltage is very low.

```
// the sensor communicates using SPI, so include the library:
#include <SPI.h>

#define uchar unsigned char
#define uint unsigned int

//数组最大长度
#define MAX_LEN 16

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//set the pin
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const int chipSelectPin = 10;
const int NRSTPD = 9;

//MF522命令字
#define PCD_IDLE              0x00               //NO action;取消当前命令
#define PCD_AUTHENT           0x0E               //验证密钥
#define PCD_RECEIVE           0x08               //接收数据
#define PCD_TRANSMIT          0x04               //发送数据
#define PCD_TRANSCEIVE        0x0C               //发送并接收数据
#define PCD_RESETPHASE        0x0F               //复位
#define PCD_CALCCRC           0x03               //CRC计算

//Mifare_One卡片命令字
#define PICC_REQIDL           0x26               //寻天线区内未进入休眠状态
#define PICC_REQALL           0x52               //寻天线区内全部卡
#define PICC_ANTICOLL         0x93               //防冲撞
#define PICC_SElECTTAG        0x93               //选卡
#define PICC_AUTHENT1A        0x60               //验证A密钥
#define PICC_AUTHENT1B        0x61               //验证B密钥
#define PICC_READ             0x30               //读块
#define PICC_WRITE            0xA0               //写块
#define PICC_DECREMENT        0xC0               //扣款
#define PICC_INCREMENT        0xC1               //充值
#define PICC_RESTORE          0xC2               //调块数据到缓冲区
#define PICC_TRANSFER         0xB0               //保存缓冲区中数据
#define PICC_HALT             0x50               //休眠


//和MF522通讯时返回的错误代码
#define MI_OK                 0
#define MI_NOTAGERR           1
#define MI_ERR                2


//------------------MFRC522寄存器---------------
//Page 0:Command and Status
#define     Reserved00            0x00   
#define     CommandReg            0x01   
#define     CommIEnReg            0x02   
#define     DivlEnReg             0x03   
#define     CommIrqReg            0x04   
#define     DivIrqReg             0x05
#define     ErrorReg              0x06   
#define     Status1Reg            0x07   
#define     Status2Reg            0x08   
#define     FIFODataReg           0x09
#define     FIFOLevelReg          0x0A
#define     WaterLevelReg         0x0B
#define     ControlReg            0x0C
#define     BitFramingReg         0x0D
#define     CollReg               0x0E
#define     Reserved01            0x0F
//Page 1:Command    
#define     Reserved10            0x10
#define     ModeReg               0x11
#define     TxModeReg             0x12
#define     RxModeReg             0x13
#define     TxControlReg          0x14
#define     TxAutoReg             0x15
#define     TxSelReg              0x16
#define     RxSelReg              0x17
#define     RxThresholdReg        0x18
#define     DemodReg              0x19
#define     Reserved11            0x1A
#define     Reserved12            0x1B
#define     MifareReg             0x1C
#define     Reserved13            0x1D
#define     Reserved14            0x1E
#define     SerialSpeedReg        0x1F
//Page 2:CFG   
#define     Reserved20            0x20 
#define     CRCResultRegM         0x21
#define     CRCResultRegL         0x22
#define     Reserved21            0x23
#define     ModWidthReg           0x24
#define     Reserved22            0x25
#define     RFCfgReg              0x26
#define     GsNReg                0x27
#define     CWGsPReg           0x28
#define     ModGsPReg             0x29
#define     TModeReg              0x2A
#define     TPrescalerReg         0x2B
#define     TReloadRegH           0x2C
#define     TReloadRegL           0x2D
#define     TCounterValueRegH     0x2E
#define     TCounterValueRegL     0x2F
//Page 3:TestRegister    
#define     Reserved30            0x30
#define     TestSel1Reg           0x31
#define     TestSel2Reg           0x32
#define     TestPinEnReg          0x33
#define     TestPinValueReg       0x34
#define     TestBusReg            0x35
#define     AutoTestReg           0x36
#define     VersionReg            0x37
#define     AnalogTestReg         0x38
#define     TestDAC1Reg           0x39 
#define     TestDAC2Reg           0x3A  
#define     TestADCReg            0x3B  
#define     Reserved31            0x3C  
#define     Reserved32            0x3D  
#define     Reserved33            0x3E  
#define     Reserved34     0x3F
//-----------------------------------------------

//4字节卡序列号，第5字节为校验字节
uchar serNum[5];

uchar  writeData[16]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100};  //初始化 100元钱
uchar  moneyConsume = 18 ;  //消费18元
uchar  moneyAdd = 10 ;  //充值10元
//扇区A密码，16个扇区，每个扇区密码6Byte
 uchar sectorKeyA[16][16] = {{0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF},
                             {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF},
                             //{0x19, 0x84, 0x07, 0x15, 0x76, 0x14},
                             {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF},
                            };
 uchar sectorNewKeyA[16][16] = {{0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF},
                                {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xff,0x07,0x80,0x69, 0x19,0x84,0x07,0x15,0x76,0x14},
                                 //you can set another ket , such as  " 0x19, 0x84, 0x07, 0x15, 0x76, 0x14 "
                                 //{0x19, 0x84, 0x07, 0x15, 0x76, 0x14, 0xff,0x07,0x80,0x69, 0x19,0x84,0x07,0x15,0x76,0x14},
                                 // but when loop, please set the  sectorKeyA, the same key, so that RFID module can read the card
                                {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xff,0x07,0x80,0x69, 0x19,0x33,0x07,0x15,0x34,0x14},
                               };

void setup() {               
   Serial.begin(9600);                       // RFID reader SOUT pin connected to Serial RX pin at 2400bps
 // start the SPI library:
  SPI.begin();

  pinMode(chipSelectPin,OUTPUT);             // Set digital pin 10 as OUTPUT to connect it to the RFID /ENABLE pin
    digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);          // Activate the RFID reader
  pinMode(NRSTPD,OUTPUT);               // Set digital pin 10 , Not Reset and Power-down
    digitalWrite(NRSTPD, HIGH);

  MFRC522_Init(); 
}

void loop()
{
   uchar i,tmp;
 uchar status;
        uchar str[MAX_LEN];
        uchar RC_size;
        uchar blockAddr; //选择操作的块地址0～63
        String mynum = "";


  //寻卡，返回卡类型
  status = MFRC522_Request(PICC_REQIDL, str);
  if (status == MI_OK)
  {
                        //Serial.println("Card detected");
   //Serial.print(str[0],BIN);
                        //Serial.print(" , ");
   //Serial.print(str[1],BIN);
                        //Serial.println(" ");
  }

  //防冲撞，返回卡的序列号 4字节
  status = MFRC522_Anticoll(str);
  memcpy(serNum, str, 5);
  if (status == MI_OK)
  {

                        //Serial.println("The card's number is  : ");
   Serial.print(serNum[0]);
                        //Serial.print(" , ");
   //Serial.print(serNum[1],BIN);
                        //Serial.print(" , ");
   //Serial.print(serNum[2],BIN);
                        //Serial.print(" , ");
   //Serial.print(serNum[3],BIN);
                        //Serial.print(" , ");
   //Serial.print(serNum[4],BIN);
                        Serial.println(" ");

                        // Should really check all pairs, but for now we'll just use the first

                        if(serNum[0] == 148) {
                          Serial.println("Hello Mousa");
                          digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
                          delay(5000);
                          digitalWrite(5, LOW);

                        } else if(serNum[0] == 112) {
                          Serial.println("Hello Mousa");
                          digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
                          delay(5000);
                          digitalWrite(6, LOW);
                        } else      {              
                          Serial.println("Incorrect");
                          digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
                          delay(5000);
                          digitalWrite(6, LOW);
                        }
                        //delay(5000);
  }
                //Serial.println(" ");
  MFRC522_Halt();   //命令卡片进入休眠状态             

}

/*
 * 函 数 名：Write_MFRC5200
 * 功能描述：向MFRC522的某一寄存器写一个字节数据
 * 输入参数：addr--寄存器地址；val--要写入的值
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void Write_MFRC522(uchar addr, uchar val)
{
 digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);

 //地址格式：0XXXXXX0
 SPI.transfer((addr<<1)&0x7E);
 SPI.transfer(val);

 digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：Read_MFRC522
 * 功能描述：从MFRC522的某一寄存器读一个字节数据
 * 输入参数：addr--寄存器地址
 * 返 回 值：返回读取到的一个字节数据
 */
uchar Read_MFRC522(uchar addr)
{
 uchar val;

 digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);

 //地址格式：1XXXXXX0
 SPI.transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E) | 0x80);
 val =SPI.transfer(0x00);

 digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);

 return val;
}

/*
 * 函 数 名：SetBitMask
 * 功能描述：置RC522寄存器位
 * 输入参数：reg--寄存器地址;mask--置位值
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void SetBitMask(uchar reg, uchar mask) 
{
    uchar tmp;
    tmp = Read_MFRC522(reg);
    Write_MFRC522(reg, tmp | mask);  // set bit mask
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：ClearBitMask
 * 功能描述：清RC522寄存器位
 * 输入参数：reg--寄存器地址;mask--清位值
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void ClearBitMask(uchar reg, uchar mask) 
{
    uchar tmp;
    tmp = Read_MFRC522(reg);
    Write_MFRC522(reg, tmp & (~mask));  // clear bit mask
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：AntennaOn
 * 功能描述：开启天线,每次启动或关闭天险发射之间应至少有1ms的间隔
 * 输入参数：无
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void AntennaOn(void)
{
 uchar temp;

 temp = Read_MFRC522(TxControlReg);
 if (!(temp & 0x03))
 {
  SetBitMask(TxControlReg, 0x03);
 }
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：AntennaOff
 * 功能描述：关闭天线,每次启动或关闭天险发射之间应至少有1ms的间隔
 * 输入参数：无
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void AntennaOff(void)
{
 ClearBitMask(TxControlReg, 0x03);
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：ResetMFRC522
 * 功能描述：复位RC522
 * 输入参数：无
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void MFRC522_Reset(void)
{
    Write_MFRC522(CommandReg, PCD_RESETPHASE);
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：InitMFRC522
 * 功能描述：初始化RC522
 * 输入参数：无
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void MFRC522_Init(void)
{
 digitalWrite(NRSTPD,HIGH);

 MFRC522_Reset();

 //Timer: TPrescaler*TreloadVal/6.78MHz = 24ms
    Write_MFRC522(TModeReg, 0x8D);  //Tauto=1; f(Timer) = 6.78MHz/TPreScaler
    Write_MFRC522(TPrescalerReg, 0x3E); //TModeReg[3..0] + TPrescalerReg
    Write_MFRC522(TReloadRegL, 30);          
    Write_MFRC522(TReloadRegH, 0);

 Write_MFRC522(TxAutoReg, 0x40);  //100%ASK
 Write_MFRC522(ModeReg, 0x3D);  //CRC初始值0x6363 ???

 //ClearBitMask(Status2Reg, 0x08);  //MFCrypto1On=0
 //Write_MFRC522(RxSelReg, 0x86);  //RxWait = RxSelReg[5..0]
 //Write_MFRC522(RFCfgReg, 0x7F);     //RxGain = 48dB

 AntennaOn();  //打开天线
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_Request
 * 功能描述：寻卡，读取卡类型号
 * 输入参数：reqMode--寻卡方式，
 *    TagType--返回卡片类型
 *     0x4400 = Mifare_UltraLight
 *    0x0400 = Mifare_One(S50)
 *    0x0200 = Mifare_One(S70)
 *    0x0800 = Mifare_Pro(X)
 *    0x4403 = Mifare_DESFire
 * 返 回 值：成功返回MI_OK
 */
uchar MFRC522_Request(uchar reqMode, uchar *TagType)
{
 uchar status; 
 uint backBits;   //接收到的数据位数

 Write_MFRC522(BitFramingReg, 0x07);  //TxLastBists = BitFramingReg[2..0] ???

 TagType[0] = reqMode;
 status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, TagType, 1, TagType, &backBits);

 if ((status != MI_OK) || (backBits != 0x10))
 {   
  status = MI_ERR;
 }

 return status;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_ToCard
 * 功能描述：RC522和ISO14443卡通讯
 * 输入参数：command--MF522命令字，
 *    sendData--通过RC522发送到卡片的数据,
 *    sendLen--发送的数据长度  
 *    backData--接收到的卡片返回数据，
 *    backLen--返回数据的位长度
 * 返 回 值：成功返回MI_OK
 */
uchar MFRC522_ToCard(uchar command, uchar *sendData, uchar sendLen, uchar *backData, uint *backLen)
{
    uchar status = MI_ERR;
    uchar irqEn = 0x00;
    uchar waitIRq = 0x00;
    uchar lastBits;
    uchar n;
    uint i;

    switch (command)
    {
        case PCD_AUTHENT:  //认证卡密
  {
   irqEn = 0x12;
   waitIRq = 0x10;
   break;
  }
  case PCD_TRANSCEIVE: //发送FIFO中数据
  {
   irqEn = 0x77;
   waitIRq = 0x30;
   break;
  }
  default:
   break;
    }

    Write_MFRC522(CommIEnReg, irqEn|0x80); //允许中断请求
    ClearBitMask(CommIrqReg, 0x80);   //清除所有中断请求位
    SetBitMask(FIFOLevelReg, 0x80);   //FlushBuffer=1, FIFO初始化

 Write_MFRC522(CommandReg, PCD_IDLE); //NO action;取消当前命令 ???

 //向FIFO中写入数据
    for (i=0; i<sendLen; i++)
    {  
  Write_MFRC522(FIFODataReg, sendData[i]);   
 }

 //执行命令
 Write_MFRC522(CommandReg, command);
    if (command == PCD_TRANSCEIVE)
    {   
  SetBitMask(BitFramingReg, 0x80);  //StartSend=1,transmission of data starts 
 }  

 //等待接收数据完成
 i = 2000; //i根据时钟频率调整，操作M1卡最大等待时间25ms ???
    do
    {
  //CommIrqReg[7..0]
  //Set1 TxIRq RxIRq IdleIRq HiAlerIRq LoAlertIRq ErrIRq TimerIRq
        n = Read_MFRC522(CommIrqReg);
        i--;
    }
    while ((i!=0) && !(n&0x01) && !(n&waitIRq));

    ClearBitMask(BitFramingReg, 0x80);   //StartSend=0

    if (i != 0)
    {   
        if(!(Read_MFRC522(ErrorReg) & 0x1B)) //BufferOvfl Collerr CRCErr ProtecolErr
        {
            status = MI_OK;
            if (n & irqEn & 0x01)
            {  
    status = MI_NOTAGERR;   //??  
   }

            if (command == PCD_TRANSCEIVE)
            {
                n = Read_MFRC522(FIFOLevelReg);
               lastBits = Read_MFRC522(ControlReg) & 0x07;
                if (lastBits)
                {  
     *backLen = (n-1)*8 + lastBits;  
    }
                else
                {  
     *backLen = n*8;  
    }

                if (n == 0)
                {  
     n = 1;   
    }
                if (n > MAX_LEN)
                {  
     n = MAX_LEN;  
    }

    //读取FIFO中接收到的数据
                for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                {  
     backData[i] = Read_MFRC522(FIFODataReg);   
    }
            }
        }
        else
        {  
   status = MI_ERR; 
  }

    }

    //SetBitMask(ControlReg,0x80);           //timer stops
    //Write_MFRC522(CommandReg, PCD_IDLE);

    return status;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_Anticoll
 * 功能描述：防冲突检测，读取选中卡片的卡序列号
 * 输入参数：serNum--返回4字节卡序列号,第5字节为校验字节
 * 返 回 值：成功返回MI_OK
 */
uchar MFRC522_Anticoll(uchar *serNum)
{
    uchar status;
    uchar i;
 uchar serNumCheck=0;
    uint unLen;


    //ClearBitMask(Status2Reg, 0x08);  //TempSensclear
    //ClearBitMask(CollReg,0x80);   //ValuesAfterColl
 Write_MFRC522(BitFramingReg, 0x00);  //TxLastBists = BitFramingReg[2..0]

    serNum[0] = PICC_ANTICOLL;
    serNum[1] = 0x20;
    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, serNum, 2, serNum, &unLen);

    if (status == MI_OK)
 {
  //校验卡序列号
  for (i=0; i<4; i++)
  {  
    serNumCheck ^= serNum[i];
  }
  if (serNumCheck != serNum[i])
  {  
   status = MI_ERR;   
  }
    }

    //SetBitMask(CollReg, 0x80);  //ValuesAfterColl=1

    return status;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：CalulateCRC
 * 功能描述：用MF522计算CRC
 * 输入参数：pIndata--要读数CRC的数据，len--数据长度，pOutData--计算的CRC结果
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void CalulateCRC(uchar *pIndata, uchar len, uchar *pOutData)
{
    uchar i, n;

    ClearBitMask(DivIrqReg, 0x04);   //CRCIrq = 0
    SetBitMask(FIFOLevelReg, 0x80);   //清FIFO指针
    //Write_MFRC522(CommandReg, PCD_IDLE);

 //向FIFO中写入数据
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {  
  Write_MFRC522(FIFODataReg, *(pIndata+i));  
 }
    Write_MFRC522(CommandReg, PCD_CALCCRC);

 //等待CRC计算完成
    i = 0xFF;
    do
    {
        n = Read_MFRC522(DivIrqReg);
        i--;
    }
    while ((i!=0) && !(n&0x04));   //CRCIrq = 1

 //读取CRC计算结果
    pOutData[0] = Read_MFRC522(CRCResultRegL);
    pOutData[1] = Read_MFRC522(CRCResultRegM);
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_SelectTag
 * 功能描述：选卡，读取卡存储器容量
 * 输入参数：serNum--传入卡序列号
 * 返 回 值：成功返回卡容量
 */
uchar MFRC522_SelectTag(uchar *serNum)
{
    uchar i;
 uchar status;
 uchar size;
    uint recvBits;
    uchar buffer[9];

 //ClearBitMask(Status2Reg, 0x08);   //MFCrypto1On=0

    buffer[0] = PICC_SElECTTAG;
    buffer[1] = 0x70;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
     buffer[i+2] = *(serNum+i);
    }
 CalulateCRC(buffer, 7, &buffer[7]);  //??
    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buffer, 9, buffer, &recvBits);

    if ((status == MI_OK) && (recvBits == 0x18))
    {  
  size = buffer[0];
 }
    else
    {  
  size = 0;   
 }

    return size;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_Auth
 * 功能描述：验证卡片密码
 * 输入参数：authMode--密码验证模式
                 0x60 = 验证A密钥
                 0x61 = 验证B密钥
             BlockAddr--块地址
             Sectorkey--扇区密码
             serNum--卡片序列号，4字节
 * 返 回 值：成功返回MI_OK
 */
uchar MFRC522_Auth(uchar authMode, uchar BlockAddr, uchar *Sectorkey, uchar *serNum)
{
    uchar status;
    uint recvBits;
    uchar i;
 uchar buff[12];

 //验证指令+块地址＋扇区密码＋卡序列号
    buff[0] = authMode;
    buff[1] = BlockAddr;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
    {   
  buff[i+2] = *(Sectorkey+i);  
 }
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {   
  buff[i+8] = *(serNum+i);  
 }
    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_AUTHENT, buff, 12, buff, &recvBits);

    if ((status != MI_OK) || (!(Read_MFRC522(Status2Reg) & 0x08)))
    {  
  status = MI_ERR;  
 }

    return status;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_Read
 * 功能描述：读块数据
 * 输入参数：blockAddr--块地址;recvData--读出的块数据
 * 返 回 值：成功返回MI_OK
 */
uchar MFRC522_Read(uchar blockAddr, uchar *recvData)
{
    uchar status;
    uint unLen;

    recvData[0] = PICC_READ;
    recvData[1] = blockAddr;
    CalulateCRC(recvData,2, &recvData[2]);
    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, recvData, 4, recvData, &unLen);

    if ((status != MI_OK) || (unLen != 0x90))
    {
        status = MI_ERR;
    }

    return status;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_Write
 * 功能描述：写块数据
 * 输入参数：blockAddr--块地址;writeData--向块写16字节数据
 * 返 回 值：成功返回MI_OK
 */
uchar MFRC522_Write(uchar blockAddr, uchar *writeData)
{
    uchar status;
    uint recvBits;
    uchar i;
 uchar buff[18];

    buff[0] = PICC_WRITE;
    buff[1] = blockAddr;
    CalulateCRC(buff, 2, &buff[2]);
    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buff, 4, buff, &recvBits);

    if ((status != MI_OK) || (recvBits != 4) || ((buff[0] & 0x0F) != 0x0A))
    {  
  status = MI_ERR;  
 }

    if (status == MI_OK)
    {
        for (i=0; i<16; i++)  //向FIFO写16Byte数据
        {   
         buff[i] = *(writeData+i);  
        }
        CalulateCRC(buff, 16, &buff[16]);
        status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buff, 18, buff, &recvBits);

  if ((status != MI_OK) || (recvBits != 4) || ((buff[0] & 0x0F) != 0x0A))
        {  
   status = MI_ERR;  
  }
    }

    return status;
}


/*
 * 函 数 名：MFRC522_Halt
 * 功能描述：命令卡片进入休眠状态
 * 输入参数：无
 * 返 回 值：无
 */
void MFRC522_Halt(void)
{
 uchar status;
    uint unLen;
    uchar buff[4];

    buff[0] = PICC_HALT;
    buff[1] = 0;
    CalulateCRC(buff, 2, &buff[2]);

    status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, buff, 4, buff,&unLen);
}
```

[image: Arduino RFID]

Comment: Do you mean low output voltage on digital outputs 5 and 6?  You shouldn't connect LEDs straight to the digital outputs.

Comment: Add 1 kohm resistors in series with both LEDs and try again !

Comment: output voltage i lower than 2v so don't need to use any resistor -_-

Comment: **You're turning things around.** You say: my output is 2 V, not 5. We say: it's because no Resistors on the LEDs. Then you say: don't need them because 2 V comes out. Do you want 5 V or not ???? Then use the resistors with the LEDs as we said. **Always use series resistors with LEDs.**

Comment: it not because the LED have resistor or no, i test the output voltage before putting the LED by voltmeter it was 2v only. my problem solved by 'JRE', he say i have to add pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
pinMode(6,OUTPUT);

Answer (score 4):

I checked the arduino docs, and you have another problem.

You must define the digital output pins as outputs before you use them, just as you did for the chipSelect pin.

You need to do

```
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
```

in the setup() method.

---

You **NEED** series resistors for the LEDs, no matter how much you think you don't.

The arduino digital outputs aren't made to deliver any real amounts of current.  You should be glad that you had the other bug.  Drawing too much current from an arduino output could cause damage to the arduino processor.

Even [the Arduino Blink tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink) makes use of a series resistor:
[image]

---

You seem to have been driving the LEDs from the internal pull up resistors for the digital I/O pins - that's not a good idea.

Also, directly driving a relay from the digital I/O pins is a **Bad Idea** as this can destroy the arduino processor.

1. Configure the pins as outputs
2. Use proper circuitry to drive relays of LEDs connected to the outputs.

There are numerous schematics on the internet showing how to interface relays to an arduino.

If you are using a purchased relay module, then it may have the needed drivers and protection parts built in.  Read the documentation.  If it was built for arduino users, then probably includes all the needed parts and example code for using it.

Comment: i test the output voltage without LED  by voltmeter its about 2v too.

Comment: it can't run the Relay module

Comment: What do you mean "it can't run the Relay module?"

Comment: thank you very much bro, i changed code :     pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
pinMode(6,OUTPUT); it worked well

Comment: the voltage now is 5v exactly

Comment: @mousa: Please post ALL relevant information in future questions.  It would have been nice of you to show that you have the relay module connected as well as the LEDs.